# FFmpeg: Video with crossfade and move up / down effects keeps the first image height

Tags: video, ffmpeg, effects

I'm creating a video using 4 images. The image sizes are following:

1st, 2nd and 3rd images sizes are 1280x1600. And the last image sizes are 1280x1280

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 \ 
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.jpg \
-i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[0]crop=1280:1280:ow:((ih-oh)/5)*t[f0]; \
[1]crop=1280:1280:ow:(ih-oh)-((ih-oh)*t/5),format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[f1]; \
[2]crop=1280:1280:ow:((ih-oh)/5)*t,format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8/TB[f2]; \
[3]format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+12/TB[f3]; \
[0][f0]overlay[bg1];[bg1][f1]overlay[bg2];[bg2][f2]overlay[bg3];[bg3][f3]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 4:a -b:v 4000k -movflags +faststart -t 20 -s 1280x1280 out.mp4
```

[image]

So, the problem is that it seems it's keeping the first image's sizes for the whole video and the move up / down animations are being done in the red section in the above image. It keeps the first image like a background ( even I set the `-s 1280x1280` for the video )

Note: This issue appears when I merged *Crossfade* effect with the *Move Up / Down*. When it was only with the *Move Up / Down* effect, the Crop was worked correctly without any unnecessary section at the bottom

When I'm changing the first image with the 1280x1280 sizes, it looks good and without unnecessary section at the bottom

***EDIT***

The correct answer to this question you can find [here](https://superuser.com/a/1522501/1103036)